# monochrome dithering in JavaScript (Bayer, Atkinson, Floyd–Steinberg)

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, matrix, dithering

I'm playing with webcam filters in HTML5. Got an [Atkinson dither](http://blog.flickr.net/2012/04/01/your-photos-re-envisioned/) working pretty well for that old-school Mac feeling.

[image: meemoo cam to dither]
[Live](http://meemoo.org/iframework/#gist/3721129) | [Code](https://github.com/meemoo/iframework/blob/gh-pages/src/nodes/image-monochrome-worker.js)

Now I'm trying to make a Bayer ordered dithering option for a 1989 Gameboy feeling.

I [read up on the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_dithering), but I'm having trouble converting this pseudocode to JavaScript:

```
for each y
  for each x
    oldpixel := pixel[x][y] + threshold_map_4x4[x mod 4][y mod 4]
    newpixel := find_closest_palette_color(oldpixel)
    pixel[x][y] := newpixel
```

Are there any examples out there in AS3, PHP, or JS? Could you explain what is happening with `threshold_map_4x4[x mod 4][y mod 4]`?

---

[image: gameboy style gif] (made with the [Meemoo Gameboy GIFerizer](http://meemoo.org/iframework/#gist/3722026))

Figured it out. In Wikipedia it says "For example, in monochrome rendering, if the value of the pixel (scaled into the 0-9 range) is less than the number in the corresponding cell of the matrix, plot that pixel black, otherwise, plot it white." In js I got good results by averaging the current pixel (0-255) and the map's value (15-240) and comparing it to the threshold (normally 129):

```
var map = (imageData.data[currentPixel] + bayerThresholdMap[x%4][y%4]) / 2;
imageData.data[currentPixel] = (map < threshold) ? 0 : 255;
```

Here is my whole monochrome function with different algorithms:

```
var bayerThresholdMap = [
  [  15, 135,  45, 165 ],
  [ 195,  75, 225, 105 ],
  [  60, 180,  30, 150 ],
  [ 240, 120, 210,  90 ]
];

var lumR = [];
var lumG = [];
var lumB = [];
for (var i=0; i<256; i++) {
  lumR[i] = i*0.299;
  lumG[i] = i*0.587;
  lumB[i] = i*0.114;
}

function monochrome(imageData, threshold, type){

  var imageDataLength = imageData.data.length;

  // Greyscale luminance (sets r pixels to luminance of rgb)
  for (var i = 0; i <= imageDataLength; i += 4) {
    imageData.data[i] = Math.floor(lumR[imageData.data[i]] + lumG[imageData.data[i+1]] + lumB[imageData.data[i+2]]);
  }

  var w = imageData.width;
  var newPixel, err;

  for (var currentPixel = 0; currentPixel <= imageDataLength; currentPixel+=4) {

    if (type === "none") {
      // No dithering
      imageData.data[currentPixel] = imageData.data[currentPixel] < threshold ? 0 : 255;
    } else if (type === "bayer") {
      // 4x4 Bayer ordered dithering algorithm
      var x = currentPixel/4 % w;
      var y = Math.floor(currentPixel/4 / w);
      var map = Math.floor( (imageData.data[currentPixel] + bayerThresholdMap[x%4][y%4]) / 2 );
      imageData.data[currentPixel] = (map < threshold) ? 0 : 255;
    } else if (type === "floydsteinberg") {
      // Floyd–Steinberg dithering algorithm
      newPixel = imageData.data[currentPixel] < 129 ? 0 : 255;
      err = Math.floor((imageData.data[currentPixel] - newPixel) / 16);
      imageData.data[currentPixel] = newPixel;

      imageData.data[currentPixel       + 4 ] += err*7;
      imageData.data[currentPixel + 4*w - 4 ] += err*3;
      imageData.data[currentPixel + 4*w     ] += err*5;
      imageData.data[currentPixel + 4*w + 4 ] += err*1;
    } else {
      // Bill Atkinson's dithering algorithm
      newPixel = imageData.data[currentPixel] < threshold ? 0 : 255;
      err = Math.floor((imageData.data[currentPixel] - newPixel) / 8);
      imageData.data[currentPixel] = newPixel;

      imageData.data[currentPixel       + 4 ] += err;
      imageData.data[currentPixel       + 8 ] += err;
      imageData.data[currentPixel + 4*w - 4 ] += err;
      imageData.data[currentPixel + 4*w     ] += err;
      imageData.data[currentPixel + 4*w + 4 ] += err;
      imageData.data[currentPixel + 8*w     ] += err;
    }

    // Set g and b pixels equal to r
    imageData.data[currentPixel + 1] = imageData.data[currentPixel + 2] = imageData.data[currentPixel];
  }

  return imageData;
}
```

I'd appreciate optimization hints.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are all of my monochrome dither functions, usable as a web worker: https://github.com/meemoo/meemooapp/blob/master/src/nodes/image-monochrome-worker.js

Live demo with webcam: http://meemoo.org/iframework/#gist/3721129

Comment: @500-InternalServerError :) fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I do this as a debug code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img    = new Image();
img.src    = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHDY8.png";
img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width  = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    ctx.drawImage( this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height );

    var imageData  = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    var depth      = 32;


    // Matrix
    var threshold_map_4x4 = [
        [  1,  9,  3, 11 ],
        [ 13,  5, 15,  7 ],
        [  4, 12,  2, 10 ],
        [ 16,  8, 14,  6 ]
    ];

    // imageData
    var width  = imageData.width;
    var height = imageData.height;
    var pixel  = imageData.data;
    var x, y, a, b;

    // filter
    for ( x=0; x<width; x++ )
    {
        for ( y=0; y<height; y++ )
        {
            a    = ( x * height + y ) * 4;
            b    = threshold_map_4x4[ x%4 ][ y%4 ];
            pixel[ a + 0 ] = ( (pixel[ a + 0 ]+ b) / depth | 0 ) * depth;
            pixel[ a + 1 ] = ( (pixel[ a + 1 ]+ b) / depth | 0 ) * depth;
            pixel[ a + 2 ] = ( (pixel[ a + 2 ]+ b) / depth | 0 ) * depth;
            //pixel[ a + 3 ] = ( (pixel[ a + 3 ]+ b) / depth | 3 ) * depth;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData( imageData, 0, 0);

};

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

And it seems to work fine, you can change the depth variable to change the posterization.

Comment: Since it is monochrome you could change it to: ```pixel[ a ] = pixel[ a + 1 ] = pixel[ a + 2 ] = ( (pixel[ a ]+ b) / depth | 0 ) * depth;```

Comment: Check the console, I have a problem with cross domain image (well I'm using an old browser...). So I go to the image url, open the console and copy paste the code and it's working fine (http://tof.canardpc.com/view/f47567dc-d06b-4fea-8b9f-ac7c23e9ceb8.jpg) or maybe you want another result ?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted monochrome output. I put my algorithms in the original question, and made this live demo: http://meemoo.org/iframework/#gist/3721129